# How to count total numbers in specific cell

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, excel-2010, excel-2007

How can we count total numbers in one cell.

for e.g.  I have 1422.45 in cell F11, Then count value should be 6 considering 1 4 2 2 4 5

here blanks,special character,text etc. should not be counted in other words only numbers should be counted.

This can be solved Either by formula or by vba.

any help ll be appriciated. thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
Public Function CountDigits(value As String)
CountDigits = 0

For x = 1 To Len(value)
Ext = Mid$(value, x, 1)
If InStr(1, "0123456789", Ext, vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
CountDigits = CountDigits + 1
End If
Next

End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also do it by formula:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--ISNUMBER(FIND(MID(A1,ROW($A$1:INDEX($A:$A,LEN(A1))),1),"0123456789")))
```

Comment: Thanks - basically same method as VBA.